# Is there a possible `idstring` that would the `make_msgid` not compliant with RFC 2822?

Tags: python, email, rfc2822

The [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/efc5d37671d2b9f31850a9edaa495fadae038759/Lib/email/utils.py#L174%5D) mentions that `make_msgid` generates an RFC 2822 compliant Message-ID and also has the option to add an `idstring` to strengthen uniqueness.

Is there any value of `idstring` one could add that would make the resultant id generated by `make_msgid` not complaint with RFC 2822? I read the [RFC spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.4) but I am not sure.

I ask because when I sent an email to a gmail address with a messaged id generated by `make_msgid` (with <foobar> as the `idstring`), I noticed that gmail changed the Message-ID to something like ...SPTMIN_ADDED_BROKEN@mx.google.com. However when I send an email using a messaged id from `make_msgid` *without* and `idstring`, gmail did not change anything and I could see the message id was the same as the one I generated originally.

Comment: Ah I think the issue was the < and > characters. When I removed those and just used foobar as the idstring gmail did not change the Message-ID.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, brokets in the `idstring` are precisely an example of invalid tokens; another example would be adding a second `@`.